# Android WebRTC crashes

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to disconnect the call by pressing back button and the application crashes with this error. I am using Pierre Chabardes 's AndroidRTC app on eclipse.
https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

I have also builded the latest WebRTC **libjingle_peerconnection_so.so** & **libjingle_peerconnection.jar** through linux machine.

```
04-10 12:20:16.695: E/rtc(29060): #
04-10 12:20:16.695: E/rtc(29060): # Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 926
04-10 12:20:16.695: E/rtc(29060): # Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast<MediaSourceInterface*>(j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 1)
04-10 12:20:16.695: E/rtc(29060): # Unexpected refcount.
04-10 12:20:16.695: E/rtc(29060): #
04-10 12:20:16.695: A/libc(29060): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 29060
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After going through multiple hours of testing, I had figured out that the Socket which was initially created was not closed properly in the onDestroy() method on line .

Its something like this there:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    for (Peer peer : peers.values()) {
        peer.pc.dispose();
    }
    videoSource.dispose();
    factory.dispose();
    client.disconnect();
    client.close();
}
```

it needs to be close by this way :

```
public void onDestroy() {
    for (Peer peer : peers.values()) {
        peer.pc.dispose();
    }
    videoSource.dispose();
    factory.dispose();
    client.off();<---- You need to turn OFF and then disconnect  and then close it.
    client.disconnect();
    client.close();
}
```

Comment: What libjingle's version did you use? I use version 8981 with `client.off()` but it cannot work.

Comment: now i am facing issue in Disable/enable video stream can any one help?

Comment: try to stop the video stream by videoSource.stop(); and then you need to dispose the video stream by videoSource.dispose() only then you would be able to enable the stream next time or else your app would crash.