# How to properly close Android WebRTC connection?

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, webrtc

I am using WebRTC Library in a service and an activity. In "onDestroy" of both components, I am trying to fully disconnect so that with the service/activity running again, the device can join room with the same procedure.

Firstly, I have tried these old code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566419/android-webrtc-crashes) Combined with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130567/fatal-signal6-during-disposing-peerconnection-webrtc):

```
public void onDestroy() {
    for (Peer peer : peers.values()) {
        peer.pc.dispose();
    }
    videoSource.dispose();
    factory.dispose();
    client.off();<---- You need to turn OFF and then disconnect  and then close it.
    client.disconnect();
    client.close();
}
```

But the activity/service crashes with this error (There was no leaking in my code):

```
Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Then I learned that disposing connections and factory makes up for this error. So I just set them to null. The onDestroy callback turned out to be like this:

```
if(videoTrackFromCamera != null) videoTrackFromCamera.dispose();
    //if(rootEglBase != null) rootEglBase.release(); //Causes Crash:: # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/sdk/android/src/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 1031
    //    # last system error: 0
    //    # Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast<MediaStreamInterface*>(j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 2)
    //    # Unexpected refcount.
    if(audioSource != null) audioSource.dispose();
    if(localAudioTrack != null) localAudioTrack.dispose();

    if(localMediaStream != null) localMediaStream.dispose();
    if(mRemoteMediaStream != null) mRemoteMediaStream.dispose();
    audioConstraints = null;

    if (factory != null) {
        factory.stopAecDump();
    }
    if (peerConnection != null) {
        //peerConnection.dispose();
        //peerConnection.close();
        peerConnection = null;
    }
    if (factory != null) {
        //factory.dispose(); //causes error  Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed
        factory = null;
    }
    if (socket != null) {
        sendMessage("finished");
        socket.disconnect();
        socket.close();
    }
```

Now everything is fine except that only sometimes I get a crash with this error:

```
Channel {0} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
        Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
```

Is there a better way to end WebRTC connection?
If I want to stay in the room but stop sending and or receiving streams, what is the optimal way?

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution how to properly close and reopen the connection without crashing :) I use https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-in-jetpack-compose/tree/main/webrtc-android as a good starting point with much logic that is already implemented here(like audio).

#### Close

```
localAudioTrack.setEnabled(false)
localVideoTrack.setEnabled(false)

audioHandler.stop() // See https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-in-jetpack-compose/blob/main/webrtc-android/app/src/main/kotlin/io/getstream/webrtc/sample/compose/webrtc/audio/AudioHandler.kt#L69
videoCapturer.stopCapture()

remoteVideoTrackFlow.replayCache.forEach { it.setEnabled(false) } // Disable remote videoTrack

peerConnection.onTrack(null)
peerConnection.onRemoveTrack(null)
peerConnection.onIceCandidate(null)
peerConnection.onIceConnectionChange(null)
peerConnection.onSignalingChange(null)
// And finally close connection
peerConnection.close()
```

And the most important part **you dont neet to close/dispose `PeerConnectionFactory`, because it leads to crash in my case.**

#### Open

Just recreate a `peerConnectionFactory.makePeerConnection` new peer connection. In my case I just recreate `WebRtcSessionManagerImpl` from the lib above(https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-in-jetpack-compose/blob/main/webrtc-android/app/src/main/kotlin/io/getstream/webrtc/sample/compose/webrtc/sessions/WebRtcSessionManagerImpl.kt)

Comment: btw If you don't want to add 
```
implementation "io.getstream:stream-webrtc-android:1.0.4"
```

You can change a code and use directly `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'`